# Mysql nested query optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I have a table that logs various transactions for a CMS. It logs the username, action, and time. I have made the following query to tell me how many transactions each user made in the past two days, but it is so slow its faster for me to send a bunch of separate querys at this point. Am I missing a fundamental rule for writing nested queries?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `username`
   , ( SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM `ActivityLog`
       WHERE `username`=`top`.`username`
         AND `time` > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 2 DAY
     ) as `count`
FROM `ActivityLog` as `top`
WHERE 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
   SELECT username
        , COUNT(*) AS count
   FROM ActivityLog
   WHERE time > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 2 DAY
   GROUP BY username
```

An index on `(username, time)` would be helpful regarding speed.

---

If you want users with 0 transcations (the last 2 days), use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    act.username
  , COALESCE(grp.cnt, 0) AS cnt
FROM ActivityLog act
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT username
           , COUNT(*) AS count
      FROM ActivityLog
      WHERE time > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 2 DAY
      GROUP BY username
    ) AS grp
  ON grp.username = act.username
```

or, if you have a `users` table:

```
SELECT 
    u.username
  , COALESCE(grp.cnt, 0) AS cnt
FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT username
           , COUNT(*) AS count
      FROM ActivityLog
      WHERE time > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 2 DAY
      GROUP BY username
    ) AS grp
  ON grp.username = u.username
```

Another way, similar to yours, would be:

```
   SELECT username
        , SUM(IF(time > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 2 DAY, 1, 0))
          AS count
   FROM ActivityLog
   GROUP BY username
```

or even this (because true=1 and false=0 for MySQL):

```
   SELECT username
        , SUM(time > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 2 DAY)
          AS count
   FROM ActivityLog
   GROUP BY username
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much ypercube, that worked amazingly faster. Can you explain why that is faster? I am talking it took 34 sec previously, and now it took .09 sec.

But, it doesnt return the users with 0 transactions , where the previous query did.

Comment: You can run `EXPLAIN yourquery` and `EXPLAIN myquery` to see how MySQL "plans" to run the queries. I can make guesses but it really depends on the indexes you have on the table, its size and distibution of data.

Comment: What is surely better, is that this is one query, and then a grouping. If you have an index on `time`, the WHERE check will be fast, in both queries. But in your case, MySQL may have to run a subquery (and scan the whole table) for every different `username` in the table!

Comment: Thank you VERY much. I do have a users table and I modified your query to utilize my schema. Its so fast, got .007 sec. I have never even heard of the COALESCE function. Thanks again.

Comment: @Kevin: What indexes do you have on `ActivityLog` ?

Comment: @ypercube I have username, action, time and just recently added username_time

Answer (score 0):

No need for nesting...

```
SELECT `username`, COUNT(`username`) as `count` FROM `ActivityLog` WHERE `time` > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 2 DAY GROUP BY `username`
```

Also don't forget to add an INDEX on `time` if you want to make it even faster